# Access Data from Database with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, undefined

I have tried just about every solution and I know my database returns values if i hard code in the php so the issues is returning the values or determining if it is actually sent as post. It gets to the success function and alerts Worked but I am getting undefined for Item ID.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.check').click(function(){
alert("Step1");
var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
alert(thisID);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XXX.PHP",
    data: { "ID": thisID},
    cache: false,
    async:true,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("WORKED");
        alert(data.ItemID);
    }

});
}); 
});
```

Here is the PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['ID']))
{
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
function retrieve($ID)
{
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  database1.menu  WHERE ItemID = $ID");

if($stmt->num_rows) //if there is an ID of this name
{  
 $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
 echo $row;
 print json_encode($row);   

}
 }
```

Comment: Switch `type: "GET",` to `type: "POST",` and commence face-palm. I've face-palmed on this issue before lol

Comment: why are you looking @ `_POST` when you are doing ajax GET?

Comment: A far superior debugging tool is `console.log();` by the way which is used in conjunction with the Console window in any modern browser such as IE8 and up. Don't be a stranger to the Network tab either because beautiful harmony is made there. In your situation you would do `console.log(data);` instead of `alert("WORKED");` in your AJAX Success handler

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxx/xxx/xxx/xx.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I tried learns way and that isn't working either I do appreciate the console.log tho as Dreamweaver was showing an alert that chrome didn't for some reason. Also mega-facepalm for the GET.

Comment: I have never used DreamWeaver for anything other than uber-simple HTML pages before but I will have to assume the error that you're getting is because of DreamWeaver. Stick with debugging strictly in the web browser because people don't browse the internet in DreamWeaver so it is not a reliable representation of the challenges faced when visiting your page in a browser. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` sounds like you are trying to access a domain other than your own. Simply put "You cannot send an AJAX request to www.site2.com if the code is running on www.site1.com"...continued below

Comment: Unless www.site2.com is configured to accept such requests. This is relevant because DreamWeaver probably simulates your URL as localhost

Comment: I have to access another sites php because of phonegap. phonegap doesn't allow for local php and as much as i would like to agree with you about dreamweaver it's the only way i know how to work with phonegap at the moment . Is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of the PhoneGap situation. In all honestly you probably need to start a new question such as `Getting AJAX to work in PhoneGap` in order to get the proper attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Not sure if this is what you need.

```
$(".check").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var thisID = $this.attr('id');

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: base_url + "url.php", 
             data: {
                 id: thisID          
             },
             dataType: "text",  
             cache:false,
             success: 
              function(data){
                 alert(data);
              }
         });

    return false;
});
```